# NHibernate - where .. in .. and future

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, future, queryover

I have two models: Thing and ThingStatus. Thing has an Id and some other fields. ThingStatus is a model which stores Status enum corresponding to id of Thing. Now I want to fetch Things that have Status != Completed.
What I try to do now looks like this:

```
var unfinishedIds = session.QueryOver<ThingStatus>()
    .Where(t => t.Status != StatusEnum.Completed)
    .Select(t => t.Id)
    .List<long>()
    .ToArray();

var unfinishedThings = session.QueryOver<Thing>()
    .WhereRestriction(t => t.Id)
    .IsIn(unfinishedIds)
    .List<Thing>();
```

As far as I understand, in such case unfinishedIds will be fetched from database and only after that used as a filter in unfinishedThings query. Is there any way to avoid that and have the query optimizer select the right way to do that? I've heard there are some futures available with nhibernate but I'm not sure how they'd help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery if you can't create a NHibernate relationship between the two entities. No relationship --> no `JoinAlias` (or `JoinQueryOver`) possible.

With a subquery:

```
var unfinishedIds = QueryOver.Of<ThingStatus>()
    .Where(t => t.Status != StatusEnum.Completed)
    .Select(t => t.Id);

var unfinishedThings = session.QueryOver<Thing>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(t => t.Id).In(unfinishedIds)
    .List<Thing>();
```

(note the use of `QueryOver.Of<>`)

The query is equivalent to writing:

```
SELECT * FROM Things WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM ThingsStatuses WHERE Status <> 'Completed')
```